# Interface not recognized

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have an interface declared in its own header MyInterface.h:

```
class MyInterface{
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface(){}
    virtual void initialize() = 0;
    virtual void newValueSound(int stream, double value) = 0;
    virtual void newValueAlg1(int stream, double value) = 0;
    virtual void newValueAlg2(int stream, double value) = 0;
};
```

Whenever I include this header and try to use the interface, for example:

```
#include "MyInterface.h"

void someMethod(){
    MyInterface *interface;
}
```

I get strange compile errors on the line:

error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition
error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type '<unnamed-tag>'

What is wrong with my code?

EDIT:
Header has include guards.
I use Eclipse CDT with Microsoft compiler.

The whole header:

```
#ifndef MYINTERFACE_H_
#define MYINTERFACE_H_

class MyInterface{
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface(){}
    virtual void initialize() = 0;
    virtual void newValueSound(int stream, double value) = 0;
    virtual void newValueAlg1(int stream, double value) = 0;
    virtual void newValueAlg2(int stream, double value) = 0;
};

#endif
```

and the class it is used in:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

#include <asio.h>
#include "Stream.h"
#include "MyInterface.h"

class MicApp {
private:
    long inputChannelCount;
    Stream **streams;
    MyInterface *interface;
public:
    MicApp(MyInterface *interface);
    void initializeASIODrivers();
    char **getDriverNames(int *numberOfDrivers);
    bool loadDriver(char *driverName);
    ASIOError initDriver(ASIODriverInfo *asioDriverInfo);
    long getChannelCount();
    double getSampleRate();
    void activateStream(bool activate, int stream);
    ASIOError startASIO();
    ASIOError stopASIO();
    ASIOError exitDriver();
};

#endif
```

Note that "Stream" is another class and it is used without any problems.

Comment: You are missing a double quote inside your import, this might be a typo though.

Comment: Didn't you forget to close the quote after `#include "MyInterface.h`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo here. TY David for correcting that. In the code, the quotes are properly closed.

Comment: This compiles fine for me, (gcc 4.6.1).  What compiler are you using?  Can you post the command line?

Comment: You're going to have to show some more code, there's nothing wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: The error messages should show you the line numbers of the errors - you should post the code near them. I doubt the problem is in the code you've posted, since there are no `struct` or `enum` declarations there.

Comment: Does the header file have include guards? Forgetting them is a common source of "type redefinition" errors.

Comment: What is the name of the source file that you are including this in?  Does it have a .c or .cpp extension?

Comment: Everything is C++. I use .cpp for source and .h for headers.

Comment: I'd check for problems in "Stream.h"...maybe an unclosed bracket?  Also, you don't need to include MyInterface.h here, I would use a predeclaration here and include it in your cpp file.

Comment: I deleted the header with the interace and started from scratch by small steps. The code compiles now. So either this was Microsoft compiler bug or I accidentaly put some obcure whitespace character somewhere that interfered with compilation.

Comment: I FINALLY FIGURED IT! The thing was that the string "interface" is typedef'ed in ObjBase.h. So I cannot use "interface" as identifier. If I use another string as identifier, it works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing was that the string "interface" is typedef'ed in ObjBase.h. So I cannot use "interface" as identifier. If I use another string as identifier, it works ok

Comment: Actually, it is #defined, so adding something like `#ifdef interface` `#undef interface` `#endif` will fix the issue.